# Change lists landing page (Example.aspx)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I've done it already for another list, but I can't find the option to do so anymore.

I want to change the link to a list from this:

```
/Lists/Tools/Short Description.aspx
```

to this:

```
/Lists/Tools/ListOverview.aspx
```

So changing the name of the "landing page" of the list.

Is this possible somewhere? As I said I wasn't able to find the option anywhere anymore. Maybe one can just do it when adding a list to a site and then it's set forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Follow below steps:**

- Go to list settings
- Navigate at bottom of page to Views section.
- Click on the view name you want to set as default. (in your case ListOverview )
- You will find a mark as default view checkbox below the view name.
- Mark it.
- Click Okay and you are done.

**OR another approach**

- Go to the `/Lists/Tools/ListOverview.aspx`
- Click on List Tab in ribbon
- Click On Modify View
- You will find a mark as default view checkbox below the view name.
- Mark it.
- Click Okay and you are done.

Comment: Ahh, I see. This is the link to a view I've created for my list. Allright. Got it! Quick answer, thanks a lot! :)